# Query on REST URI design

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I have a centralservice API which I am designing. Now `centralserive` will receive requests from numerous sub-central services that are deployed at different locations.

An example endpoint would look like `/api/v1/centralservice/activity`

One of the suggestions I received while designing was to include the sub-central-id [the location ID where the subcentral service is deployed] in the URI. In that case, the endpoint would look like - `/api/v1/centralservice/{subcentral-id}/activity`. The reason I am told was that in case of a network error/issue, it would be easy to identify from which location the request was made by looking at the logs. I have not seen such a practice in any projects that I have worked on.

Per my understanding, the forward slashes should define the hierarchical relationship of the resources. In my opinion, the same scenario should be handled by including the `{subcentral-id}` either in the header or the request body.

Could anyone please throw some light on this and share if it's a good/bad practice to follow?

Thank you

Comment: Keep that id in header, encoded. Don't change the api signature

Comment: This is likely to be closed as opinion-based, but for my two cents: you're right. The URI should not contain information that is only used for debugging purposes. Use a (custom) header for that. Although I have seen projects that used the standard `User-Agent` header for this.

Comment: To add on to what @rickdenhaan mentioned, URIs are just pointers to resources and should not be used to extract knowledge. The reasoning behind that is that servers are free to change the URI structure anytime it wants to and clients that perform some knowledge extraction will break as a consequence. And the aim of REST is that clients are decoupled from services to allow servers to evolve freely in future. A core premise of REST is that clients are taught everything they need to know from servers anyway, as such URIs are just references to resources and nothing more

Answer (score 1):

> Could anyone please throw some light on this and share if it's a good/bad practice to follow?

First thing that you should notice: the machine's *don't care* what spellings you use for your resource identifiers, so long as they are consistent with the production rules defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).

When we are designing a URI, what we are really doing is choosing some population of *people* and trying to make things easier for them.

So if the operators who review your access logs in the event of network errors are a top priority for you, then it makes a lot of sense to design the URI with their needs in mind.

---

> Per my understanding, the forward slashes should define the hierarchical relationship of the resources.

The description of the path part of a URI, taken from RFC 3986, is

> The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical form, that, along with data in the non-hierarchical query component (Section 3.4), serves to identify a resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority (if any).

The path is a hierarchy of identification data; but that doesn't necessarily imply that the hierarchy of identification and the hierarchy of resources map one to one.  Complex resource models don't *have* a neat hierarchy, necessarily.

For example, in HTTP, you can

```
DELETE /a HTTP/1.1
```

And that doesn't imply anything about what is going to happen to `/a/` or `/a/b` or `/a/b/c` ....  General purpose components on the web don't *guess* what is happening to resources based on the spelling of their identifiers.

---

There are a lot of different ways that you could choose to encode identifying data like `subcentral-id` in your URI.  See [RFC 6570](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570).

Answer (score 0):

When you're developing integrations it's generally easier to work with URIs and query parameters than have set specific headers or form a body in some specific format. URIs are also easy to share since most of the data is in a single string.

If the endpoints goal is to just provide information on request I'd avoid asking client to provide headers or body for anything other than say authentication.